# Should I use Bootstrap or Media queries for web page responsiveness?

Tags: html, css

I am currently finishing up a project for my portfolio and I am wondering if I should use Bootstrap or media queries to make my webpage responsive. Do jobs prefer one over the other or does it not matter?

Comment: Bootstrap is a framework; media queries are a function of CSS. Comparing the two is a false comparison - they serve totally different purposes.

Comment: In any case, the question as it's currently written is primarily opinion-based, which is generally a poor fit for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. See [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer.

Bootstrap and media queries are not totally the same. For example, I have used Bootstrap for a project. The row and grid system of bootstrap is repsonsive. So it works perfectly on mobile devices, as Bootstrap offers predefinied classes and media queries for them.

However, you also may need media queries even if you are using Bootstrap, so did I. Media queries define the behaviour at different device sizes.

In conclusion, Bootstrap is a great tool which offers responsive elements. Bootstrap uses media queries, but you will always need media queries for custom changes or for own elements.